# can an app programatically tweak chatter message when user hits submit?

Tags: force.com, api, chatter

For example, when a user enters a long URL, we want our Salesforce Org to automagically use an API of a URL shortening service to transform it into a short URL.  Any ideas how this can be done?

Answer (score 2):

You could write a trigger on the [feedItem](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_feeditem.htm) object. Somthing like this:

```
trigger shortenURL on FeedItem (before insert) {

    for(feedItem feed: trigger.new){
       if(feed.type=='LinkPost'){
           //call your url shortening logic here.
           feed.linkurl = 'https://changetoshorturl';
       }
    }
}
```